# Cannot display Mysql search results from search in a different div

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to display MySQL results (with and without a search) using three divisions. Div 1 has radio buttons for selecting the viewing the results. Div 2 has a text that states all members are displayed, a text search box for Name, and a drop-down menu for Type. The results of the search are displayed in Div 3.

When All Members is selected the text "Display All Members" shows in Div 2 and the correct data is displayed in Div 3 (works correctly). When the Name radio button is selected the correct text search box displays in Div 2 but I receive the following errors in Div 3:

Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/desgar20/elrenochamber.com/member_dir_test2.php on line 171

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/desgar20/elrenochamber.com/member_dir_test2.php on line 173
Could not access database:

If I enter text into the search box and submit, Div 2 and Div 3 go blank

I am using javascript to show/hide the divisions and php for the search.

I have searched for answers but have not found anything to resolve this issue.  I don't know what I am missing.  Help- -need advice.

```
        <style type="text/css">
            .box {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Show or application part based on selection 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).attr("value")=="all"){
                        $(".box").not(".all").hide();
                        $(".all").show();
                        $(".all_listing").show();
                    }
                    if($(this).attr("value")=="name"){
                        $(".box").not(".name").hide();
                        $(".name").show();
                        $(".all_name").show();
                    }
                    if($(this).attr("value")=="type"){
                        $(".box").not(".type").hide();
                        $(".type").show();
                        $(".all_type").show();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            require_once 'php/dbconnect.php';   // Connect to database
            $connection = db_connect();
        ?>


        <div id="container">

            <div id="service">

                <div id="web">
                    <img width="150px" src="images/search1.png" />
                    <h3>Member <strong><span class="green">Directory</span></strong></h3>
                    <strong>View Members By:</strong><br /><br />
                    <div id="sortOptions">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="sortRadio" value="all"> All Members</label><br />
                        <label><input type="radio" name="sortRadio" value="name"> Name</label><br />
                        <label><input type="radio" name="sortRadio" value="type"> Type</label>
                    </div><!-- sortOptions -->
                </div><!-- end web -->

                <div id="vector">

                    <div class="all box">
                        <h3>Display <strong><span class="green">All Members</span></strong></h3>
                        <p>All Members Displayed</p>
                    </div><!-- all box -->

                    <div class="name box">
                        <h3>Display by <strong><span class="green">Member Name</span></strong></h3>
                        <p><form name="namesearch" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"> 
                            Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="find">
                            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search Names">
                        </form></p>
                    </div><!-- name box -->

                    <div class="type box">
                        <h3>Display by <strong><span class="green">Member Type</span></strong></h3>
                        <p><form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
                            Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="type" id="type">
                            <option value="">-- Select A Type --</option>
                            <?php
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM select_type";   //create type drop-down menu
                                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 
                                while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
                                echo "<option value='". $line['type'] ."'>". $line['type']."</option>";
                                } 
                            ?> 
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" name="searchType" value="Search Types">
                        </form>
                    </div><!-- type box -->

                </div><!-- end vector -->

            </div><!-- end service-->

            <div id="media" class="group">

                <div class="all_listing box">
                    <p>Directory Listing</p>
                    <!-- Start Directory Listing -->
                    <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY name";   // Database query and results
                        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            // Check record for website
                            if ($row['web']!== "") {
                                echo "<a target=blank href=". $row['web'] . ">" .$row["name"] . "</a><br> " .
                                "". $row["type"] . "<br>" .
                                "Address: " . $row["physicaladdress"] . "<br>" .
                                "Phone: " . $row["phone"] . "<br>" . "<hr>";
                            }
                            else {
                                echo $row["name"]. "<br> " .
                                "". $row["type"] . "<br>" .
                                "Address: " . $row["physicaladdress"] . "<br>" .
                                "Phone: " . $row["phone"] . "<br>" . "<hr>";
                            }
                        }
                        $connection->close();
                    ?>
                </div><!-- all_listing box -->

                <div class="all_name box">
                    <p>Results based on Name Search</p>
                    <?php
                        if (isset($_POST['search'])) {  // Has "Select Names button ben pushed
                            $find = $_POST['find'];
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE name LIKE '%" . $find . "%' ";
                            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                            if(! $result) {
                                die ('Could not access database: ' . mysqli_error());
                            }
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                // Check record for website
                                if ($row['web']!== "") {
                                    echo "<a target=blank href=". $row['web'] . ">" .$row["name"] . "</a><br> " .
                                    "". $row["type"] . "<br>" .
                                    "Address: " . $row["physicaladdress"] . "<br>" .
                                    "Phone: " . $row["phone"] . "<br>" . "<hr>";
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo $row["name"]. "<br> " .
                                    "". $row["type"] . "<br>" .
                                    "Address: " . $row["physicaladdress"] . "<br>" .
                                    "Phone: " . $row["phone"] . "<br>" . "<hr>";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </div><!-- all_name box -->
    </body>
</html>
```

I modified the code as recommendation but still receive the same errors as mention above.  Here is the area that I am having difficulty with:

This is the division (div 1) that will display the search option in div 2:

```
<div id="web">
    <div id="sort_options">
        <label><input type="radio" name="sortRadio" value="name"> Name</label><br />
    </div><!-- sort_options -->
</div><!-- end web -->
```

This is the search feature for div 2:

```
<div class="name box">
    <form name="namesearch" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"> 
        Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="find">
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search Names">
    </form></p>
</div>
```

This is the php code in div 3 to run the query with input from div 2:

```
<div class="all_name box">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) 
{   
    $find = $_POST['find'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE name LIKE '%" . $find . "%' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if ( $result == false ) 
    {
        echo ("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    else
     {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            // Check record for website
            if ($row['web']!== "") 
            {
                echo "<a target=blank href=". $row['web'] .">" .$row["name"] . "</a><br> " .
                "". $row["type"] . "<br>" .
                "Address: " . $row["physicaladdress"] . "<br>" .
                "Phone: " . $row["phone"] . "<br>" . "<hr>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo $row["name"]. "<br> " .
                "". $row["type"] . "<br>" .
                "Address: " . $row["physicaladdress"] . "<br>" .
                "Phone: " . $row["phone"] . "<br>" . "<hr>";
            }
        }
    }
}
    ?>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You really should separate that code into proper layers...

Comment: Always interested in learning to work smarter.  I will look into proper layers.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change this snippet:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY name";   // Database query and results
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

to *at least*

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY name";   // Database query and results
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($result !== false && $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Reason: If your query is faulty, `$result` will have the value `false` which will cause the given error.

Better code would be like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY name";   // Database query and results
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if ( $result == false )
{
      // handle error with mysqli_... functions
}
else
{
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     ...
```

As always: take the error as standard, success is the exception!

Comment: as of the error messages, it's quite obvious that `$connection` is not a valid mysqli connection. I assume it's even plain undefined.

Comment: that was my first thought, however the same connection is used in other connections successfully (i.e. the "Type" drop-down menu and the complete list of all records in the database).  I'll keep working it.  Thanks for your input.